# Calculating possible combinations between sets

Tags: combinatorics

So I have a tool that generates a profile dependent on data intrinsic to a file. For this, I get 24 values based each on a different aspect of the data, each with three possible states.

My question is, what is the number of possible combinations for these markers?

Comment: Isn't it $3^{24}$ ?

Comment: $3\times 3\times 3\times ....$ How many times do you think?

Comment: 282429536481 if everybody is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is any combination possible?

Assuming that values are independent, then you have $3^{24}$ possible values.

If there is some kind of dependency (for example: if `value1` is `stateA` then `value2` can only be `stateA` or `stateC`) then you have to give us the dependencies and recalculate.

Comment: They're all independent yes, $3^{24}$ it is then. That was far simpler a solution than I thought it would be.